# Splunk interesting field exclusion

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk, splunk-calculation

i have 4 fields (`Name` , `age`, `class`, `subject`) in one index (Student_Entry) and i want to add total events but i want to exclude those events who has any value in subject field.

I tried the below two ways

```
index=Student_Entry   Subject !=* | stats count by event
index=Student_Entry   NOT Subject= * | stats count by event
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NOT` and `!=` operators are similar, but not equivalent.  `NOT` will return events with no value in the Subject field, whereas `!=` will not.  In your case, use `!=`.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Search/NOTexpressions

`stats count by event` does nothing because there is no field called 'event'.  To count events, just use `stats count`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were right using `index=Student_Entry Subject !=*`

Then you can add only - `| stats count`

Comment: the `!=` is *NOT* equivalent to `NOT` in SPL

Comment: Yes, Supriya was asking to not count events that have nothing in "subject". If I were to use NOT it will still be showing the events that have nothing in "subject".

Comment: You need to use `NOT subject=*` vs `subject!=*` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, too:

```
index=Student_Entry
| where isnull(subject)
| stats count
```